# What to do with excess Wham bars

Tags: cake

I currently have 50 wham bars in my kitchen , I went a bit ott at wholesalers and after eating one my jaw felt like it was going to give in .

Can any of you offer up an ingenious solution for my excess wham bars ?

Wham bars are basically pink taffy bars with sweet and sour bits in , very nice and very unhealthy !

Comment: I think the best thing to do would be to give them away, but not necessarily to people you like. http://www.tangerineuk.net/our-brands/wham/wham-chew-bars/

Comment: I guess one could make some kind of caramel sauce from them... you have enough material to experiment :)

Comment: Or... get them very cold, grind them down and use them as a bulk additive in some kind of cake (they should stand in for sugar pretty well, after all thats what they are mostly :)

Comment: @ElmerCat : I'm guessing there's a reason they have [one labeled 'softer chew'](http://www.tangerineuk.net/our-brands/wham/wham-cosmic-chews/)